# Adding color to text to this HTML code without using CSS

Tags: python, html

Hi I am just trying to find if there is a way to change the color of the text that is being displayed here. This HTML is generated in Python, which I am fluent in, but not HTML. Is there just a simple way to make this white instead of black (what it is displayed at).

```
color_map_fe00bde8bb8162c8ee694c2404df9330.g.call(color_map_fe00bde8bb8162c8ee694c2404df9330.xAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("y", 21)
    .text("% of Flightsz Expected to be Delayed over 1hr period");
```

I heard the only way my be CSS, but this script is over 3000 lines of code. Just hoping for a one-liner solution.

Thanks!

Comment: You really should not do it, but something like adding this to the start of your text: <span style='color:#aa0000'> and then add </span> where the color should end.

Answer (score 0):

There was a way to do it in HTML 4 where you would use the `<font>` tag. However this is not supported in HTML5. Also, that is not really recommended. Right now, I think there is no way without CSS

You may use CSS using `<style>` tag

Answer (score 0):

yeah I belive you can add bootstrap frameworks to your code and then edit the html font colors by giving them specific class names.

Comment: Which is sadly not a one line answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).